# Prove that if deg(vertex) > number of vertices/2, then G contains a triangle.

Tags: discrete-mathematics, graph-theory

A triangle would mean a cycle of length 3. To show a cycle, I would have to prove that each vertex has degree 2.

However, I am unsure of how to show the above using the assumption that deg(vertex) > number of vertices/2. While this intuitively makes sense, how can I go about proving it?

Can the Degree-Sum formula be used?

Comment: Do you mean the deg($v$) for all $v\in V$ is greater than $\frac{|V|}{2}$?

Comment: Is your hypothesis that **every** vertex has degree $> n/2$, where the number of vertices is $n$?  Show that if $a$ and $b$ are two neighbours, the sets of neighbours of $a$ and $b$ have nonempty intersection.

Comment: False. The star $K_{1,n}$ has a vertex of degree $n$ which is greater than number of vertices$/2$ when $n\ge2.$

Answer (score 1):

So, given a graph $(V,E)$, for each $v \in V$, let us define $N(v)$ via:
$$
N(v) = \{q \in V : (q,v) \in E\}
$$
Take a vertex $v_1 \in V$, and identify another vertex $v_2 \in N(v)$. We will show that,
$$
N(v_1) \cap N(v_2) \neq \emptyset,
$$
which will prove the claim. Assume for the sake of contradiction that this intersection is empty. Then, $|N(v_1) \cup N(v_2)|=|N(v_1)|+|N(v_2)|>|V|$, a contradiction! Hence, $\exists v_3 \in N(v_1)\cap N(v_2)$, such that $v_1-v_2-v_3$ forms a triangle.

Comment: Can you explain what N(v) is? Is that the set of all vertices that v shares an edge with? Also, I do not understand why |N(v1)∩N(v2)|=|N(v1)|+|N(v2)|.

Comment: For a given vertex $v$, $N(v)$ is the set of all vertices that share an edge with $v$. On the second item above, it was a typo; which is fixed now.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming $deg(v)=\frac{|V|}{2}$ for $\forall v \in V$ we can form a complete bipartite graph $K_{\frac{|V|}{2},\frac{|V|}{2}}$, i.e., a graph with maximal number of edges without a $3$-cycle. Since $deg(v)>\frac{|V|}{2}$ there is at least one $3$-cycle in $G$.

Comment: To be more precise, we need to know that $K_{n/2,n/2}$ is the graph with the *maximum* number of edges that does not have a $3$-cycle: $\frac{n^2}{4}$ edges. This is [Mantel's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mantel%27s_theorem). Just saying that $K_{n/2,n/2}$ is maximal without a $3$-cycle is not enough, since not all graphs with minimum degree $>n/2$ contain $K_{n/2,n/2}$ as a subgraph.